# Синтаксическая ошибка NavItem JS\React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не могу понять что он от меня хочет.

```
<NavItem hidden={checkPermission({user:props.user,'/admin/manager/dashboard'})}>
    <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/admin/manager/dashboard">Dashboard</NavLink>
</NavItem>
```

Хочу что бы элемент отображался по условию есть ли у юзера доступ к этому содержимому. Почему он ругается на строку `'/admin/manager/dashboard'`?

метод `checkPermission` возвращает `bool`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `{user:props.user,'/admin/manager/dashboard'}` - у вашей строки нет ключа, вот и ругается на формат. Должно быть что то типа: `{ user: props.user, link: '/admin/manager/dashboard' }`

Comment: @SwaD точно( спасибо, слепозавр